# Gradle Build failed for the Hello World example in the Corda website

Tags: corda

I followed the IOU example on the Corda website. I have Java 1.8 121 version. 
Not sure why this problem happening.
I am running my application in my intelliJ in windows box.

I have copy pasted the gradle file content in the IOU example. Alternatively I used the same gradle file which was there in the downloaded zip itself.

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
    }
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : false]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyD,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("0.0.0.0:10009")
            adminAddress("0.0.0.0:10010")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}

task installQuasar(type: Copy) {
    destinationDir rootProject.file("lib")
    from(configurations.quasar) {
        rename 'quasar-core(.*).jar', 'quasar.jar'
    }
}
```

Below is the complete error

```
D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java>gradlew clean deployNodes
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :deployNodes
Running Cordform task
Deleting D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes
Bootstrapping local test network in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes
Generating node directory for Notary
Generating node directory for PartyA
Generating node directory for PartyD
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...

#### Error while generating node info file D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs ####
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version line: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: java <options> -jar corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
#### Error while generating node info file D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyD\logs ####
#### Error while generating node info file D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\Notary\logs ####
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version line: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: java <options> -jar corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version line: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: java <options> -jar corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

> Task :deployNodes FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
> Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.
   > Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
15 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 1 up-to-date

D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java>gradlew clean deployNodes --stacktrace
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

> Task :deployNodes
Running Cordform task
Deleting D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes
Bootstrapping local test network in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes
Generating node directory for Notary
Generating node directory for PartyA
Generating node directory for PartyD
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...

#### Error while generating node info file D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs ####
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version line: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: java <options> -jar corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
#### Error while generating node info file D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\Notary\logs ####
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version line: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: java <options> -jar corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
#### Error while generating node info file D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyD\logs ####
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version line: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: java <options> -jar corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

> Task :deployNodes FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
> Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.
   > Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.
        at net.corda.plugins.Baseform.bootstrapNetwork(Baseform.kt:244)
        at net.corda.plugins.Cordform.build(Cordform.kt:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.printNodeInfoGenLogToConsole(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:135)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:114)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:67)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:93)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:67)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:130)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\Notary\logs.
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.printNodeInfoGenLogToConsole(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:135)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:114)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:67)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:93)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:67)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:130)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\Arvinth\BlockChain\Corda\corda-java\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes\PartyD\logs.
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.printNodeInfoGenLogToConsole(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:135)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:114)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:67)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:93)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:67)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:130)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:142)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
15 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the java. I had multiple java versions. I cleaned up all java. in-fact I uninstalled all the Java, restarted, and installed freshly Java1.8_221 version.And able to solve it.